# Mobile device header going beyond width of viewport

Tags: css

There is this [site](http://nettra.net/demo-sites/wvg/development/) that if you view it on a mobile device (iPhone 6), you're able to drag the page to the left and there's this huge, open, gap. I'm not able to figure out what's causing this. Based on Browserstack's findings (maybe it's a bug?), this tends to cause (on the home page with iPhone 6/6+) device to lose the mobile menu (which should be on the top right).

Is someone able to see what's causing the width to expand beyond the viewport's size? or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it was caused by an animation script. When an element was set up to animate to come from the right, the margin scripted was causing the right margin to extend.